# Maybe and Either monads, short-circuiting, and performance

Tags: c++, performance, haskell, functional-programming, monads

[*Functional Programming in C++*](https://livebook.manning.com/book/functional-programming-in-c-plus-plus/about-this-book/), at page 214, with reference to an `expected<T,E>` monad which is the same as Haskell's `Either`, reads

> [...] as soon as any of the functions you're binding to returns an error, ***the execution will stop*** and return that error to the caller.

Then, in a caption just below, it reads

> If you call `mbind` [equivalent to Haskell's `>>=`] on an `expected` that contains an error,, `mbind` won't even invoke the transformation function; ***it will just forward that error to the result***.

which seems to "adjust" what was written earlier. (I'm pretty sure that either [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) or [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) underlines somewhere that there's no short-circuiting; if you remember where, please, remind me about it.)

Indeed, my understanding, from Haskell, is that in a chain of monadic bindings, all of the bindings happen for real; then what they do with the function passed to them as a second argument, is up to the specific monad.

In the case of `Maybe` and `Either`, when the bindings are passed a `Nothing` or `Left x` argument, then the second argument is ignored.

Still, in these specific two cases, I wonder if there's a performance penalty in doing something like this

```hs
justPlus1 = Just . (+1)
turnToNothing = const Nothing
Just 3 >>= turnToNothing >>= justPlus1
                         >>= justPlus1
                         >>= justPlus1
                         >>= justPlus1
                         >>= justPlus1
```

as in these cases the chain can't really do anything other than what it does, given that

```hs
Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
Left l >>= _ = Left l
```

Comment: I think the answer is that you don't pay anything for what comes after the `Nothing`, but you do pay for unwinding the stack before that, but I'm not entirely sure. Continuation passing style is supposed to be more efficient in some way in some contexts, for example parser combinator libraries use CPS instead of `Either` for errors.

Comment: @Hjulle, and is this CPS-thing a monad too?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: Yeah, in the most general case, continuations form a monad/transformer [`Cont`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:Cont)/[`ContT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:ContT); if you have an existing monad and don’t want to rewrite it to use CPS internally to avoid costly left-associated binds, you can use [`Codensity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html#t:Codensity) to do it automatically (shallowly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following expression:

```
result :: Maybe Int
result = x >>= f >>= g >>= h
```

In that expression, of course, `x :: Maybe a` for some `a`, and each of `f`, `g`, and `h` are functions, with `h` returning `Maybe Int` but the intermediate types of the pipeline could be anything wrapped in a `Maybe`. Perhaps `f :: String -> Maybe String`, `g :: String -> Maybe Char`, `h :: Char -> Maybe Int`.

Let's make the associativity explicit as well:

```
result :: Maybe Int
result = ((x >>= f) >>= g) >>= h
```

To evaluate the expression, each *bind* (`>>=`) must in fact be called, but not necessarily the functions `f`, `g`, or `h`. Ultimately the bind to `h` needs to inspect its left-hand argument to decide whether it is `Nothing` or `Just something`; in order to determine that we need to call the bind to `g`, and to decide that we need to call the bind to `f`, which must at least look at `x`. But once any one of these binds produces `Nothing`, we pay only for checking `Nothing` at each step (very cheap), and not for calling the (possibly expensive) downstream functions.

Suppose that `x = Nothing`. Then the bind to `f` inspects that, sees `Nothing`, and doesn't bother to call `f` at all. But we still need to bind the result of that in order to know if it's `Nothing` or not. And this continues down the chain until finally we get `result = Nothing`, having called `>>=` three times but none of the functions `f`, `g`, or `h`.

`Either` behaves similarly with `Left` values, and other monads may have different behaviors. A list may call each function one time, many times, or no times; the tuple monad calls each function exactly once, having no short-circuiting or other multiplicity features.

Comment: Oh, so in terms of _why a chain **cannot** be short-circuited_, the reason is that `>>=` is left associative. After all, given its arguments' and return value's types, it cannot be other than left associative.

Comment: Furthermore, I understand that this answer of yours holds for monads in general, regardless of the language, provided one confines to pure functions only.

Comment: Yes on both fronts.

Comment: @Enlico "in terms of why a chain cannot be short-circuited, the reason is that `>>=` is left associative" true, but `>=>` is right-associative so you just need to write `x >>= (f >=> g >=> h)` to get the actual short-circuiting behavior. furthermore, the `do` notation translates into the chain of nested lambdas also nesting on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how the Monad instances for these types work in Haskell. You say:

> Indeed, my understanding, from Haskell, is that in a chain of monadic functions, all of the functions are called,

But this demonstrably isn't the case. Indeed any time you compute

```
Nothing >>= f
```

where `f` is any function of type `a -> Maybe b`, then it is computed according to the implementation of `>>=` for the `Maybe` monad, which is:

```
Just x >>= f = f x
Nothing >>= f = Nothing
```

So `f` will indeed be called in the `Just` case, but not in the `Nothing` case. So we see that there is indeed "short circuiting". Indeed, since Haskell is lazy, every function "short circuits" by default - nothing is ever computed unless it's needed to produce a result.

It's an interesting question to ask about performance - and not a question I personally know how to answer. Certainly, as I just explained, none of the following functions in the chain will be evaluated once a `Nothing` is encountered - but performing the pattern matching to see this is unlikely to be free. Perhaps the compiler is able to optimise this away, by reasoning that it can abandon the entire calculation once it hits a `Nothing`. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Given my own example, it should be apparent that I've terribly misleaded that part of the question, confusing the monadic functions with the monadic bindings, but thanks for pointing that out, I'll correct soon.

Comment: I've reworded it more appropriately.